# How to pass custom object to REST through backbone?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I have REST web service as follows:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void testObject(final CustomVO customVO)
```

CustomVO is as follows:

```
private String id;
private String name;
private CountryVO countryVO;
private List<ShopbranchesVO> shopBranchesList
```

CustomVO contains CountryVO object which is as follows:

```
private Long id;
private String name;
```

Similarly ShopbranchesVO will have some fields.

Now I want to fill this custom object in backbone and have to pass it to testObject() REST web service. How to set list (in my case list of ShopbranchesVO) in backbone to an object?

Comment: can you put the json output of your web service here. backbone collection accepts an array of object and create a collection of models automatically for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this one

put this line of code into your render function

```
    formData = {
    // all your parameters here
    param1: param1,
    param2: param2

}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "https://www.example.com/test",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        //success handling
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handling
    }
});
```